# which collection in java should I use for sorting for higher performance?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

For the use-case I have 10 millions fields (consider every field as random number), where fields are not unique (there exists duplicates). I need to sort the data in ascending way

Which of these collection will give the sorted output with better performance?
Or maybe something else?

1. SortedSet
2. Vector
3. Array.sort
4. Collections.sort

Comment: Is it that hard to write 10 lines of code to test each possibility?

Comment: I agree. The best way to learn is to do it yourself rather than letting other people tell you.

Comment: I think you meant `Arrays.sort` not `Array` which is a different class. SortedSet doesn't allow duplicates, so it might not be the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write yourself some test code.

Write some code to populate a list of 10 million fields then use each of the above mentioned items to find out which method is fastest.

Comment: +1 And when you get your results, you can post them in a question if you don't understand them ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sets do not allow for duplicates, so (unless you have *same* items with different keys) they are out of the question.

Also, depending on what you mean by *pls consider 10 millions of random number*, (I am assuming you mean a lot of values), you might consider using a database engine for such a feat. (Something such a [HSQL](http://hsqldb.org/) could do the trick).

Dealing with all those numbers can leave you dealing with memory issues (which can be dealt with by using an [External Sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) technique). But I think that in this case, using a DB engine should give you the most bang for your buck.